# masking an animating CALayer for use in CAReplicatorLayer to create Kaleidoscope effect

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, careplicatorlayer

I'm trying to create a kaleidoscope in iOS (I'm aware there is a `CIKaleidoscope` filter but it doesn't give me the sort of effect I'm looking for so I was hoping to roll my own).  I've managed to get the effect with a still image using a `CALayer`, masking it with a triangle `CAShapeLayer` then replicating it with `CAReplicatorLayer`.  I'm now trying to animate the original image in `CALayer` to give it some movement.  I'm creating the `CALayer` and animating is using the following code:

```
UIImage *pattern = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.jpg"];
CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, pattern.size.width, pattern.size.height);
aLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0f,
                              self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0f);
aLayer.contents = (id)pattern.CGImage;

CABasicAnimation* panningAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
panningAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
panningAnimation.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(400, 400)];
panningAnimation.duration = 5.0;

[aLayer addAnimation:panningAnimation forKey:@"position"];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:aLayer];
```

I then create a triangle to be used for the mask:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable ();
CGPathMoveToPoint (path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, NULL, 57.735, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, NULL, 0, 100);
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, NULL, 0, 0);
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[shapeLayer setPath: path];
```

I can't mask the animating `CALayer` as the mask moves with the animation and I don't get the effect of the pattern moving through the triangle.

Adding the mask to the view's layer has the effect I'm after of the pattern moving through the mask in a triangle:

```
[self.view.layer setMask:shapeLayer];
```

but I can't easily replicate this using `CAReplicatorLayer`.  Is there a way I can mask the `CALayer` but keep the mask in place relative to the frame of the view and not the frame of the animating layer?  Or is there any way I can capture the animating image of the view so I can use it in a `CAReplicatorLayer`?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't easily replicate this using `CAReplicatorLayer`"? Do you have an error or something draws incorrectly?